# How cognition can be explained in Buddha's Abidhamma?

Tags: theravada, mind, abidhamma

Cognition, how it happens on one's mind? Is there any comprehensible English explanation about it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Abhidhamma, a single cognitive experience consists of 17 continuous thought moments. Here is a [useful Abhidhamma manual](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html#citta) which explains those 17 thought moments. Look for the **"Mind in its passive and active forms"** section.